# Getting a column from dataframe to write it in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I'm working on a pandas dataframe that contains 3 columns named : drugName, review and rating.
I'm trying to get the review according to its rate, if it is higher or equal to 6, so it is a positive review that I must write it in a csv file. Here is my code :

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
filename ="C:\\Users\Amin Chaari\Desktop\Book1.csv"

def user_text(filename):
     with open (filename, encoding="utf8") as f:
          datas = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ';')
          lines = [row for row in datas]
user={}
try:
    for i in range(1,5):
        if lines[0][i] != 'condition':
                print(lines[0][i])
                grouped_column = []
                for j,row in enumerate(lines):
                    if j>0:
                        grouped_column.append(row[i])
                        user.update({lines[0][i]:grouped_column})
except IndexError:
      pass
df1=pd.DataFrame(user)
df1.groupby(['review'])
return df1
df=user_text(filename)
for i in range (0,40303):
df['rating'][i]=float(df['rating'][i])

for i in range(0,40303):
if df['rating'][i] >= 6: 
   df['review'].to_csv("C:\\Users\\rev_pos.csv",encoding='utf8')
```

this the error that I get :

```
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the end of your code to the following:

```
df.loc[df['rating'][i] >= 6, 'review'].to_csv("C:\\Users\\rev_pos.csv",encoding='utf8')
```

This code filters the 'review' column by the 'rating' and then saves the result to a CSV all at once.

Comment: do you mean only the last line or all the for loop ?

Comment: The last 3 lines, or all of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot write it as a comment but here are some further suggestions for your code:

- use the read_csv functionality of the [pandas module](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) instead of the csv module

```
import pandas as pd


def user_text(filename):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';')
    return df
```

- specify the datatype upon read-in instead of iterating over the array

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
...
# assume the columns are called a and b
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';', dtype={'a': np.float32, 'b': np.float32})
```

- iterate over dataframes with df.iterrows

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    do_something(row)
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to fix this problem, here is the code :

```
for i in range (0,40303):
if df.rating[i] >= 6:
    pos_rev.append(df.review[i])

df1=pd.DataFrame(pos_rev)
file2="C:/Users/Amin Chaari/Desktop/pos.csv"
df1.to_csv(file2,sep='\t',encoding='utf8')
```